# INSERT INTO TABLE from comma separated varchar-list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, insert

Maybe i'm not seeing the wood for the trees but i'm stuck, so here's the question:

How can i import/insert a list of comma separated varchar-values into a table?
I don't mean something like this:

- `'12345678,87654321,11223344'` 
  but this:
- `'12345678','87654321','11223344'`

I have a `Split`-Function but it seems to be useless in this case, isn't it?

Here is a simple (mock-SQL) example to show what i mean:

```
Create Table #IMEIS(
    imei varchar(15)
)
INTO INTO #IMEIS(imei)
    SELECT * FROM ('012251000362843', '012251001084784', '012251001168744', '012273007269862', '012291000080227', '012291000383084', '012291000448515')
SELECT * from #IMEIS
DROP TABLE #IMEIS;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since there's no way to just pass this "comma-separated list of varchars", I assume some other system is generating them. If you can modify your generator slightly, it should be workable. Rather than separating by commas, you separate by `union all select`, and need to prepend a `select` also to the list. Finally, you need to provide aliases for the table and column in you subselect:

```
Create Table #IMEIS(
    imei varchar(15)
)
INSERT INTO #IMEIS(imei)
    SELECT * FROM (select '012251000362843' union all select '012251001084784' union all select '012251001168744' union all
                   select '012273007269862' union all select '012291000080227' union all select '012291000383084' union all
                   select '012291000448515') t(Col)
SELECT * from #IMEIS
DROP TABLE #IMEIS;
```

---

But noting your comment to another answer, about having 5000 entries to add. I believe the [256 tables per select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) limitation may kick in with the above "union all" pattern, so you'll still need to do some splitting of these values into separate statements.

Comment: This works for me although i hoped to solve this in SQL. The `256 tables per select` seems not to be a limit in this case, i have tested it with 8000 values and it works(although with very poor performance of 11 seconds).Thank you.

Answer (score 61):

Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO #IMEIS (imei) VALUES ('val1'), ('val2'), ...
```

**UPDATE:**

Apparently this syntax is only available starting on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: The list is ~5000 values long, so I'm asking for a way to do this automatically in some way. Of course i could write a small program, but i hoped that there would be a SQL way.

Comment: multiple row constructors/[table value constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) aren't supported in `VALUES` for SQL Server 2005 (it is supported from 2008 up)

Comment: Thanks Damien. I did a quick check for the syntax but I guess I was looking at 2008 instead of 2005.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Sometimes when making repetitive SQL statements, Excel can be your best friend.  Drop in a list of your 5,000 values and then use a formula in another column to format them like, in this case, "('val1')," or whatever else you might need.

Comment: SQL server only supports up to 1000 row value expressions in a given INSERT statement. Violating that results in an error of _"The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values."_ (in MSSQL 2016)

Comment: The solution to the 1000 row value expression limit is to `INSERT INTO... SELECT` the values using something like: `INSERT INTO #IMEIS (imei) SELECT IMEI FROM (VALUES ('val1'), ('val2'), ...) AS tmp(IMEI)`. This works because SELECT doesn't seem to have the same constraints.

Comment: This is a quick and working solution. And for those, who has the values in some other sources like excel or other sql output, I use delim.co to convert them to the desired format.

Answer (score 11):

Sql Server does not (on my knowledge) have in-build Split function.
Split function in general on all platforms would have comma-separated string value to be split into individual strings.
In sql server, the main objective or necessary of the Split function is to convert a comma-separated string value (‘abc,cde,fgh’) into a temp table with each string as rows.

The below Split function is Table-valued function which would help us splitting comma-separated (or any other delimiter value) string to individual string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

select top 10 * from dbo.split('Chennai,Bangalore,Mumbai',',')

the complete can be found at follownig link 
http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx

Comment: The OP already stated that they had a split function, but they don't have a single varchar containing comma separated values