# how to use dynamic strings separated by comma in sql query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-services, sql-server-2008

hello i build a webservice in visual studio 2010. i get some id's which are saved in a string looks like this:

```
string room_ids="5,11,99,42";
```

they are separated by comma. i created a `foreach` loop to split the ids and from the comma and use them in my sql query until the ids are finished. but it doesn't work. i get an error it says:

`Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric`

here is my code, thanks in advance for your help!

```
internal static List<RAUM> Raum(string RAUMKLASSE_ID, string STADT_ID, string GEBAEUDE_ID, string REGION_ID)
{       
    List<RAUM> strasseObject = new List<RAUM>();
    string[] allegebaude = GEBAEUDE_ID.Split(new char[] { ',' });

    foreach (string gebaudeid in allegebaude)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("SIND JETZT DRINNE");
        Trace.WriteLine(gebaudeid);

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID FROM RAUM r WHERE RAUMKLASSE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumklasse_ID, RAUMKLASSE_ID) AND STADT_ID = ISNULL(@Stadt_ID, STADT_ID) AND GEBAEUDE_ID = ISNULL(@gebaudeid,GEBAEUDE_ID ) AND REGION_ID = ISNULL(@Region_ID, REGION_ID)", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            if (!StringExtensions.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RAUMKLASSE_ID))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raumklasse_ID", RAUMKLASSE_ID);
            else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raumklasse_ID", DBNull.Value);

            if (!StringExtensions.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(STADT_ID))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stadt_ID", STADT_ID);
            else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stadt_ID", DBNull.Value);

            if (!StringExtensions.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GEBAEUDE_ID))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gebaudeid", GEBAEUDE_ID);
            else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gebaudeid", DBNull.Value);

            if (!StringExtensions.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(REGION_ID))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region_ID", REGION_ID);
            else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region_ID", DBNull.Value);



            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"] != DBNull.Value && rdr["ID"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        strasseObject.Add(new RAUM()
                        {
                            RaumName = rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"].ToString(),
                            RaumID = rdr["ID"].ToString()

                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return strasseObject;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the IDs in a comma-separated string (called `IDstring`) then you can just do  something like this:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT Columns FROM table WHERE ID IN (" + IDstring + ")";
```

In your specific case, don't split the original string (GEBAEUDE_ID) but use it as it is:

```
   // Don't use a foreach loop any more
   string gebaudeIdSection = " AND GEBAEUDE_ID IN (" + GEBAEUDE_ID + ") ";
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GEBAUDE_ID)) { gebaudeIdSection = ""; } // if there are no ids, let's remove that part of the query completely.
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID FROM RAUM r WHERE RAUMKLASSE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumklasse_ID, RAUMKLASSE_ID) AND STADT_ID = ISNULL(@Stadt_ID, STADT_ID)" + gebaudeIdSection + " AND REGION_ID = ISNULL(@Region_ID, REGION_ID)", con))
   { // The rest of the code is the same as before...
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i have a little problem, i can't set the gebaudeid to empty, because my string is whith []. how can i solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You don't do anything with `gebaudeid`. You need to take the original comma-separated string `GEBAUDE_ID` that you passed into the function and just use that without splitting it. Remove the bit of code that splits the string into an array.

Comment: it works but when i let the gebaude id empty i get an error: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: I have tweaked the code to completely omit that part of the query if there are no ids.

Comment: thank you it works, i tried your solution for the other ids,too. but it seems like difficult. because of the "AND" in your string. when i just give 1 parameter the "AND" in the string creates an error. i don't know how to fix that

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if (!StringExtensions.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gebaudeid))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gebaudeid", Convert.ToInt32(gebaudeid));
```

you should also pass the right parameter to your AddWithValue statement. You are iterating over the list of your ID's, that list being `allegebaude`. So you have to pass the `gebaudeid` parameter to your statement, instead of what you're doing now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you have to correct:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gebaudeid", GEBAEUDE_ID);
```

with:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gebaudeid", gebaudeid);
```

Then, try to convert the ids into integers ( for example, using `Convert.ToInt32(gebaudeid)` ) and not to pass them as strings in `AddWithValue` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't implicitly treat a comma separated list of values; instead you'll need to create a table values function to split the list of values into a table structure and then use this structure as you would normally.

Have a look at this question: [INSERT INTO TABLE from comma separated varchar-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354742/insert-into-table-from-comma-separated-varchar-list) for a sample function.