# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-insert

I keep getting this error for this very simple insert:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Players (ID_Player, Last_Name, First_Name, Position )
VALUES
(039,   'Astacio '  ,   'Pedro' , ' P ' ),
(040,   'Atchison'  ,   'Scott' , ' P ' ),
(041,   'Ayala'     ,   'Benny' , ' OF' );
GO
```

What is wrong?

Comment: are you sure that your database model is 11 (SQL 2012)?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. If I just do one line at a time the insert works. When I try multiple lines I receive this error.

Comment: What does `select @@version` tell you?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (Intel X86) Dec 10 2010 10:56:29 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: form your @@version (2005) take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6354791/1699210, maybe you'll need to retag your question.

Comment: The table valued constructor was introduced in SQL Server 2008. You are using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! Not sure how I am using 2005 when I purchased 2012 and the box in came in says 2012.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 11.0.2218.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.10.9200.16686
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.1008
Operating System 6.1.7601

Comment: When I looked at the versions I have the above running - do know why it says I am running 2005 when I looked at @@versions?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is the client tool you use to query/administrate your database.

Comment: The version of the server instance is a different matter. You can have more than one instance installed on one computer and one might be 2005 and another might be 2012. Both can be administered by the 2012 version of SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: If you only specify the server name in the connection you will connect to the "default" instance. If you want to connect to a named instance you connect to something that looks like this `servername/instancename`.

Comment: How do I run the 2012 instance?

Comment: @RobertTritt I don't think SQL Server 2005 support multi record insert like that.  You have to write 3 insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one statement then use select/union:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Players (ID_Player, Last_Name, First_Name, Position)
select 039,   'Astacio ',  'Pedro', ' P ' union
select 040,   'Atchison',  'Scott', ' P ' union
select 041,   'Ayala'   ,  'Benny', ' OF';
GO
```