# Split comma delimited string and insert to a table (int)

Tags: sql-server

i have a table with 3 columns (`First_ID,Second_ID,Third_ID`) all columns are int columns.

Now I have 3 values, first and third values are int values (1 and 0), the second value is a comma delimited string (`'188,189,190,191,192,193,194'`)

what should be my approach to populate the table like the bellow:

```
1   188 0
1   189 0
1   190 0
1   191 0
1   192 0
1   193 0
1   194 0
```

I have tried different ways but could not get it to work as i want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: google `split()` function for sql server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: i apologize for my ignorance. i googled that and im using a split function but im having difficulties populating the table

Comment: im using this function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354742/insert-into-table-from-comma-separated-varchar-list

Comment: Where do you have these comma deliminated list of values in a table ??

Comment: im sending them from my php server. so basically im trying to create an SP that i can call to populate the table

Comment: Sending them in what ? a variable? a temp table? a list?

Comment: string variable '188,189,190,191,192,193,194'

Comment: see the answer below and if it helped please accept it as your answer thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the [`Split()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns) function you have mentioned in comments,

```
-- Variable holding comma separated values
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(4000);
SET @Var =  '188,189,190,191,192,193,194'

-- Test Target Table
DECLARE @Target_Table TABLE  (First_ID INT,Second_ID INT,Third_ID INT) 

-- Insert statement
INSERT INTO @Target_Table
SELECT 1, CAST(Items AS INT) , 0 
FROM  dbo.Split(@Var, ',')  

-- Test Select
SELECT * FROM  @Target_Table
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ First_ID ║ Second_ID ║ Third_ID ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║        1 ║       188 ║        0 ║
║        1 ║       189 ║        0 ║
║        1 ║       190 ║        0 ║
║        1 ║       191 ║        0 ║
║        1 ║       192 ║        0 ║
║        1 ║       193 ║        0 ║
║        1 ║       194 ║        0 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Split is not a function in SQL Server. Using SQL Server 2012. Do i need to do any special thing

Comment: There is no SQL Server function split()

Comment: To the people commenting (correctly) that SQL Server doesn't contain a Split() function; this answer is suggesting OP create a dbo.split function as seen in the question being linked to. This answer is showing OP how to use the split function created in that other question to handle their slightly more complicated situation.

Comment: For SQL Server 2012 or above,can use "dbo.SplitString()". works similar to split() function. :)

Answer (score 24):

Better use XML for this,

```
Declare @Var nvarchar(MAX)

Set @Var ='188,189,190,191,192,193,194'

DECLARE @XML AS XML

DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR(1) =','

SET @XML = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Var,@Delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)

DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO @temp

SELECT N.value('.', 'INT') AS ID FROM @XML.nodes('X') AS T(N)

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

Comment: Isn't XLM slower than VARCHAR?

Comment: Sorry for delay. XML type may be stored little bit slower due to xml validation.

Comment: Works perfectly with no need to create database functions, so good for once-off tasks

Answer (score 7):

From SQL server 2016 onwards you can use this function `string_split`

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(4000);
SET @Var =  '188,189,190,191,192,193,194'

SELECT 1 as First_ID, value as Second_ID ,0 as Third_ID FROM string_split(@Var,',')
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2017 but `string_split` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(100)='AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD'
IF OBJECT_ID('[Comma_Split]') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [Comma_Split]
CREATE TABLE [Comma_Split](ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),COL VARCHAR(100))
while LEN(@Table)>0
BEGIN
DECLARE @COMMA INT= CHARINDEX(',', @Table)
IF @COMMA=0 SET @COMMA=LEN(@Table)+1
INSERT INTO [Comma_Split]
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Table,1,@COMMA-1)
SET @COMMA=@COMMA+1
SET @Table=SUBSTRING(@Table,@COMMA,LEN(@Table))
END
```