# Split data from colon into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a scenario where I want to split my data from colon into new column.
E.g `YR:136;YR:50;JN:275;YM:138;IN:477;WO:150;G1:10;F2:10`.

What I am looking for is this:

```
YR  136
YR   50
JN   275
YM   138
```

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How many columns appear in your output based on that CSV string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split comma delimited string and insert to a table (int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438761/split-comma-delimited-string-and-insert-to-a-table-int)

Answer (score 2):

for SQL 2016 and later you can use `STRING_SPLIT`. If not, search for `CSV Spliter`

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'YR:136;YR:50;JN:275;YM:138;IN:477;WO:150;G1:10;F2:10'

select  parsename(replace(value, ':', '.'), 2),
        parsename(replace(value, ':', '.'), 1)
from    string_split(@str, ';')
```

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` from `Sql-Server 2016` only.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the string will in the specified format every time. What I did was, first copied the same string to a new variable and added an extra `;` to the end. Then used a `WHILE` loop to split each part before each `;`. Then used `LEFT` and `RIGHT` function to take the parts before and after `:` from the splitted part. And inserted those values to a table variable `@t`.

**Code**

```
declare @str as varchar(max) ='YR:136;YR:50;JN:275;YM:138;IN:477;WO:150;G1:10;F2:10';

declare @rows as int;
set @rows = len(@str) - len(replace(@str, ';',''));

declare @t as table([col1] varchar(100), [col2] int);

declare @i as int;
set @i = 0;

declare @str2 as varchar(max);
set @str2 = @str + ';';

while(@i <= @rows)
begin
    declare @col as varchar(100);
    set @col = left(@str2, charindex(';', @str2, 1) - 1);
    set @str2 = right(@str2, len(@str2) - charindex(';', @str2, 1));    
    insert into @t([col1], [col2])
    select 
        left(@col, charindex(':', @col, 1) - 1), 
        right(@col, charindex(':', reverse(@col), 1) - 1);
    set @i += 1;
end

select * from @t;
```

**[Find a demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/842355/split-data-from-colon-into-new-column)**

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can do that using `STRING_SPLIT`.

For more information read the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: should be `STRING_SPLIT`

Answer (score 0):

First CREATE the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
GO
```

Then try this:

```
DECLARE @X VARCHAR(100), @Val VARCHAR(250) = 'YR:136;YR:50;JN:275;YM:138;IN:477;WO:150;G1:10;F2:10'

SELECT LEFT(value,CHARINDEX(':',value) - 1)A
    ,RIGHT(value,CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(value)) - 1)B
FROM dbo.fn_Split(@Val,';')
```

**Output:**

```
A   B
YR  136
YR  50
JN  275
YM  138
IN  477
WO  150
G1  10
F2  10
```

Answer (score 0):

**--FOR SQL SERVER 2016+**

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = 'YR:136;YR:50;JN:275;YM:138;IN:477;WO:150;G1:10;F2:10'

SELECT    SUBSTRING(value,0,CHARINDEX(':',value,0)) Id 
        , SUBSTRING(value,CHARINDEX(':',value,0)+1,100) Vals
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@str, ';')
```

**--FOR Older SQL SERVER**

```
DECLARE @x AS XML=''
SET @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@str,';','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)
SELECT SUBSTRING(t.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ,0,CHARINDEX(':',t.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ,0)) Id  
     , SUBSTRING(t.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ,CHARINDEX(':',t.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ,0)+1,100) Vals
FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetUnsplitGivenData]
(
@string nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS  @OutTable TABLE
(
COl1 nvarchar(max),
COl2 nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE
    (
    DATA nvarchar(max)
    )
    INSERT INTO @Temp
    SELECT @string


    INSERT INTO @OutTable(COl1,COl2)
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(Data,1,CHARINDEX(':',Data )-1) AS COl1,
            SUBSTRING(Data,CHARINDEX(':',Data )+1,LEN(Data)) AS COl2
    FROM
    (
    SELECT  Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS Data 
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    CAST( '<S>'+REPLACE(Data,';','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML ) AS Data 
    FROM @Temp
    ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY data.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
    )dt


RETURN
END
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_GetUnsplitGivenData] (
  'YR:136;YR:50;JN:275;YM:138;IN:477;WO:150;G1:10;F2:10')
GO
```

Result

```
COl1    COl2
------------
YR      136
YR      50
JN      275
YM      138
IN      477
WO      150
G1      10
F2      10
```